# how to properly resolve gsutil error

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I just installed gsutil on OS X, exactly following Google's instruction, and am seeing errors of the following format when running any gsutil command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//gsutil/gsutil", line 22, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/Users//gsutil/gsutil.py", line 101, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/Users//gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 175, in main
    command_runner = CommandRunner()
  File "/Users//gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.command_map = self._LoadCommandMap()
  File "/Users//gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 113, in _LoadCommandMap
    __import__('gslib.commands.%s' % module_name)
  File "/Users//gsutil/gslib/commands/disablelogging.py", line 16, in <module>
    from gslib.command import COMMAND_NAME
ImportError: cannot import name COMMAND_NAME
```

This error occurs on several modules in the commands directory. The only thing I could do to get rid of these errors is to remove the following modules from the directory which reference COMMAND_NAME: disablelogging, enablelogging, getacl, getcors, getdefacl, getlogging, setacl, setcors, setdefacl.

Did I do the right thing here? Is this a bug in gsutil?

Comment: Hi - what version of gsutil are you running? We renamed a number of these commands several versions ago (e.g., all logging-related commands are now consolidated under the command "logging"). Can you please try doing a fresh install from the current gsutil (v4.2) and see if you still get the problem? You can get it from https://pub.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gsutil.zip

Comment: I downloaded it from here: http://storage.googleapis.com/pub/gsutil.tar.gz  Looks like it's 4.2. I re-checked the original tar file, and those commands are not in there. I wonder if maybe I installed gsutil a while back, and the re-install of new version does not remove the old files?

Comment: Yeah, I do see artifacts in my install directory from version 3.10 with release date 2012-06-19. I don't even remember installing it! I guess the best thing is to install into clean directory. Thanks for your help!